# set_post_thumbnail_size not cropping featured images

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm developing a theme and while working on the featured images area I've noticed they aren't cropping even though I've set them to crop through set_post_thumbnail_size function.

```
/* Featured Image Thumbnails */
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 460, 250, true);
```

Using xampp, phpinfo says GD is supported. I've cleared the thumbnails and regenerated them to no avail. The div that the featured image is in is also set to 460, 250. The image just scales down to 460 wide by whatever heigh and constrains its proportions.

An imag showing the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz6Rv.png

Comment: Fixed the issue. For reference:

    /* Featured Image Thumbnails */
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    //set_post_thumbnail_size( 460, 250, true);
    add_image_size( 'my-size', 460, 250, true );

And in the area where I call to display a featured image I added:

    <?php the_post_thumbnail('my-size'); ?>

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that. Using `set_post_thumbnail_size()` should set `post-thumbnail` to your desired dimensions, and then `the_post_thumbnail()` should use `post-thumbnail` as it's default size, if none is passed.

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding you, but it seems that it is because your image is not 250px high in the first place. What is the original image dimension?

It's not really described well in the [Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size), but `460` will the maximum width that an image can be, and `250` will be the maximum height. `crop = true` simply means that if either of those dimensions are bigger, the image will be cropped to fit, as opposed to resized.

For example, take an image that is 690px by 500px -

```
/**
 * This example will crop the image to just 460x250, therefore cutting off
 * the excess pixels
 */
set_post_thumbnail_size(460, 250, true);

/**
 * This example will resize the image to 345x250, so that it fits your desired
 * dimensions while at the same time keeping the whole image
 */
set_post_thumbnail_size(460, 250);
```

Comment: I was an image that was 1000px by 1000px and I wanted it to crop excess pixels outside of 460x250. 

I reworked how the call to setting the image size was done and we're good now.

    /* Featured Image Thumbnails */
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    //set_post_thumbnail_size( 460, 250, true);
    add_image_size( 'my-size', 460, 250, true );the_post_thumbnail('my-size');

Comment: Hmm, your original attempt should have worked. I'll do some testing, there may be an issue with `set_post_thumbnail_size()` ignoring the `crop` flag.

Comment: I couldn't find it, if you do please update! Appreciate the investigation.